# Need help in identifying two IC chips

Tags: identification

I have started getting back into electronics and have been getting all my old IC chips organized into a simple storage solution. However, there are a few chips I have not been able to find any real information on.

The first one is the only one that returns any kind of internet search result. The ID number on it is DM74L93N. As far as I have found, I think it might be some kind of step counter. I haven’t been able to find out any more than that.

The other two chips don’t return any information at all. The manufacturer is NEC Japan. The number is either H760IT-726 or uPB7442C.

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't find the IC's you asked for, but just to let you know, normally i use www.alldatasheets.com BR

Comment: The DM 74L93N is most likely a National Semi Decade counter with divide-by 8.  Not sure of the others. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/Manufacturers_Prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first chip is most likely a 74L93. It is the 74L family (low-power) version of the [7493](http://www.ti.com/product/sn7493a) 4-bit counter.

The second pair of chips may be [7442 BCD to decimal converters](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls42.pdf).

Comment: The uPB7442 is confirmed from https://archive.org/download/Digital_IC_Equivalents DM74L93 is also what you say (it's also in there). I think the DM prefix was from RCA; their datasheets are generally not online.

Comment: I can't find anything about H760, assuming that's actually a part number and not the traceability info. Maybe the number is wrong and it's actually a [74H76](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/107075/ETC/54/74H76.html), which might have only H76 printed on it.

Comment: The DM prefix was from National Semiconductor, I think it stood for Digital Monolithic.  The analog components have an LM prefix (eg LM324) and in that case it stands for Linear Monolithic.

Comment: @Kevin White: Thanks for setting me straight on that. Do you happen know what the CD prefix [that RCA used] stood for? It doesn't seem worthwhile asking a question just about that...